# Extended monitor shuts off internal monitor

Tags: 14.04, external-monitor

I have Lenovo ThinkPad E545 running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have issues when I connect my external monitor via VGA. When I connect the external monitor, my internal monitor goes blank. What's interesting though, is that, in All Settings/Displays, the internal monitor is detected and shown as active even though it is shut off. When I try to move my mouse cursor to the other screen the cursor disappears (it's in the area of the internal monitor). When I check Software & Updates, everything is shown to be up to date. Also, if I shut off the external monitor via Displays Settings, my internal monitor turns on. So, it looks like both monitors are functional, but only one can be used at a time. Do you guys maybe have suggestions of what I should try out? Thanks!

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS connected 1366x768+1920+216 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       70.1     60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

PS. before posting this question, I looked everywhere for the answer, but I was not able to find anything applicable to this situation :/

Answer (score 0):

similar issue with debian 8 and HP probook laptop. turns out the internal monitor is just dimmed down. fn+F10 (keyboard combination for luminosity printed on the internal keyboard) resurrects it.